# How to insert text into TextBox in Word Macro

Tags: vba, textbox, ms-word

I created a text bo in the Word and I would like to insert text into it:

```
Sub k()
Dim Box As Shape
Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=100)
//HOW TO INSERT HERE TEXT INTO TEXT BOX


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
Sub k()
    Dim Box As Shape
    Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=100)

        'The solution for you:
        Box.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "My text comes this way"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man, Do you know the new line char? \r\n simply does not work

Comment: try any of these: `chr(10)`, `chr(13)`, `vbnewline` or `vbcrlf`... They need to go outside qutoation marks like: `"My text comes" & vbcrlf & "in new line this way"`

Comment: What about formatting? for example what if we want to make "`My text`" bold while keeping the remaining "`comes this way`" as it is.

Comment: @Top-Master, in such case you can consider using `Characters` collection similarly to this example: `Box.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(start index, length).Font.Bold = true`

Comment: For some reason, the `TextFrame2` is not accessible (it gives `The specified value is out of range.`), is there any way using `TextFrame` or `Range` (which is only available on inline-shapes)?

Comment: I believe `TextFrame2` is available as of Office 2010. Error rather refers to wrong values provided in `.Characters()` collection, but just guessing.

Comment: What if text is more than specified size, can it be auto sized to text length?