# How to creating tooltip dialog boxes in Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm converting a documentation repository from HTML to a series of individual Word documents. One of the challenges I've encountered is that the HTML has javascript popup windows linked from words and phrases in the document. These popups provide definitions for the consultants viewing the files. For instance, clicking on "Hazard Warning" brings up a small popup window that provides the text of the Hazard Warning.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="a4" style="font-weight: bold;" 
   onmouseover="if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4 &amp;&amp; 
                    typeof(BSPSPopupOnMouseOver) == 'function') 
                    BSPSPopupOnMouseOver(event);" 
   class="BSSCPopup" onclick="BSSCPopup('required_hazard_warning.htm');return false;">
   Hazard Warning</a>
```

As I convert these documents to Word, I'd like to retain the hyperlink, but instead of linking to a javascript function or website, have that clickable link launch a VBA script that brings up a dialog box populated with the text of required_hazard_warning.htm.

I've seen [this link about inserting text into a dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126517/how-to-insert-text-into-textbox-in-word-macro) and [this link about a java solution for displaying variable tooltips on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430095/tooltip-text-changing-depending-on-which-words-are-moused-over-in-text-box). I'm looking for something that's kind of a mashup of both.

My thought is that I'd have a single VBA function that shows a message box and an "ok" button to close it, and the hyperlink sends the filename parameter when clicked....

```
sub showDefinitionDialog(filename)
Dim message as String
message = getContents(filename)   <-- or whatever the proper syntax is
MessageBox.Show(message)
end sub
```

...where `filename` is a variable generated by or embedded in and read from the hyperlink. Does that make sense? Is this doable wth VBA?

Comment: @Sorceri - right now, for each "definition", the javascript opens a separate html page in a popup window. I have some flexibility in designing whatever VBA needs to grab the text FROM. It's easy enough to set separate pages up as individual text files, an Excel spreadsheet, a SharePoint list, etc. I'd like to avoid embedding the content in the Word doc...if the "Hazard Warning" changes, I'd rather edit it in a single document that I reference than try to find the 53 instances of it across all 3500 documents. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking ot use VBA than I believe you will need to use labels or textboxes so you can get the onClick event.  If you are looking for a more native looking window then you can also create your own form and show that as the "Tooltip"

the click handler would be

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    Call showDefinitionDialog(<path to file>)
End Sub



'your method to display dialog
Public Sub showDefinitionDialog(filename)
    Dim message As String
    Dim wDoc As Document
    'open the document and do not show it 
    Set wDoc = ThisDocument.Application.Documents.Open(filename, , True, , , , , , , , , False)
    'get all the text in the document
    message = wDoc.Content.Text   
    'close the document
    wDoc.Close
    'release the object
    Set wDoc = Nothing
    'show the message
    MsgBox message
End Sub
```

update based on comments

'We are going to say the label's name is Label1 and all documents reside in the same directory

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    Dim sPath as String
    sPath = Label1.Caption & ".docx"
    Call showDefinitionDialog(sPath)
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like it'll do the trick. Now how do I pass `<path to file>` (or `filename`...I can build the path) to this function via a click on a hyperlink or particular phrase in my document?

Comment: Well you have to give up on the hyperlink to do this as it cannot call a method/Macro, hence using a label with on onclick event.  I would probably come up with a naming convention that allows you to use the text in the label to create the path to the document.  So if you have Hazard Warning in the label's caption then you would have Hazard Warning.doc(x).  you would use <LabelName>.Caption to get the text of the label.

Comment: Aha...that makes sense. I was hoping for an easy solution. :) But labels sounds easy enough to rig for what I want. I'll mess around with that tonight.